# Are there any recommendations on JVM memory size for Corda nodes?

Tags: jvm, corda

I'm going through the documentation [here](https://docs.corda.net/corda-configuration-file.html) to see if there are some guidelines for node's memory allocation.  Are there minimum recommended values to be used for Corda nodes in an operational environment?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For deployment into production, the recommended hardware spec per node is:

- 8 CPU cores
- 8GB memory
- 256GB disk space

Comment: Thanks Cais.  Are these values in the official documentation?

Comment: You're welcome. I've not come across them in any of the documentation yet